# What conjunction is used with "comparative analysis"?

Tags: conjunctions

It is certain that after the phrase **comparative analysis** the preposition **of** follows and that after the first element compared the conjuction **and** is usually used. But can the conjunction **and** be replaced with the conjuction **with** in such cases? For example: the comparative analysis of the ideal model of girlhood with the real experiences of girls. Are there any other posibilities to use the phrase **comparative analysis**, i.e. using between etc.?